# After changing elastic version from 5 to 7, search query is not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, guice

I have recently changed 1 of my apps elasticsearch version from 5.6 to 7.9.3, after changing the version i am getting node not connected error.
As elastic 7 still support transport client, i am using it and in other app with same code it's working fine, but in this app, its sometime giving 200 and response and sometimes throwing node not connected error.

```
Client esClient = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new 
TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));
SearchRequestBuilder request = esClient
     .prepareSearch()
     .setIndices(indexName)
     .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
     .setSize(0);
  SearchResponse response = request.get();
```

on request.get(), this issue comes

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [{ObHmekR}{ObHmekRTRTGOFfLsBd7bHQ}{O2ZDtseBRxW_146CoZq9Tg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dim}{ml.machine_memory=17054294016, ml.max_open_jobs=20, box_type=hot, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true}]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:294) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:603) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy.execute(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:48) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.lambda$execute$0(TransportProxyClient.java:57) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:253) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:57) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:395) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:409) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:398) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [ObHmekR][127.0.0.1:9300] Node not connected
at org.elasticsearch.transport.ClusterConnectionManager.getConnection(ClusterConnectionManager.java:189) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:673) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:600) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
... 103 common frames omitted
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi Rocky, Please check the Elasticsearch logs. Normally logs can be found under "logs" directory inside Elasticsearch installation directory. Could you please also share those logs with us?

Comment: there are no logs appending in elasticsearch on these requests.